# React - wait the end of a request using Superagent

Tags: reactjs, request, state, wait, superagent

In `ComponentWillMount` I am fetching data from Node.js using Superagent.

```
  componentWillMount() {
    request.get("/appData").end((error, response) => {
      if (!error && response) {
        this.setState({ dataJSON: response.body });
      } else {
        console.log("There was an error fetching server", error);
      }
    });
  }
```

This data is saved in this.state.dataJSON in order to render it in the `render()`.

The problem is the `render()` is called before the `setState()` is effective.
But once the `setState()` updates the state of dataJSON the render is called a second time and render the data.

So I'm asking you a solution to wait for the update of dataJSON in order to call the render only when dataJSON is updated.

Comment: Why not simply show a kind of loading icon while the data is not yet fetched ? Delaying the render will show a blank page.

Comment: It's a good solution but I don't even know how to do that.

Comment: Let's say you initialize `state.dataJSON` to `null` in constructor. Then in your render, you can just do : `if (this.state.dataJSON===null) { return <div>Loading</div> } else { return <div>Your data</div> }`

Comment: Yea this is what I just did and I will take this solution ! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as delaying renders in React ([... yet](https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-react-suspense-1c73b4b0b1e6)).

There're two things you can do:

- load that state in the parent component and only mount the subcomponent when you have the data
- make the illustrated component's `render()` check whether it's still loading and either show a loading message or return `null` if it's not ready.